# How to hide data from URL string on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am beginner on `Codeigniter` so I need help.

I am making blog site with `Codeigniter`and I don't know how to hide controller class, and ID from URL.

Like I have generated following URL: http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/content/some-title/123.

1. `content` is my controller class name.
2. `some-title` is my article title.
3. `123` is my article id.

I want to keep only title to show.

For example: http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/some-title.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: In application/config/routes.php. $route['some-title/(:any)'] = 'content/some-title/$i';

Comment: This is possible but you will need an extra controller for that let me know if want to add the extra controller and still not done that task so i will answer

Answer (score 0):

You has add your **link** `config/routes.php`

http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/content/some-title/123

```
Ex: $route ['some-title/(: any)']  = 'content/some-title/$123';
```

Comment: dashes `-` are not allowed in a class method. change `some-title` method in `some_title`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'content/view/$1';
```

and in your content controller you must have a method like the one follow:

```
public funtion view($pagetitle){…}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the routes.php make sure you are using this line after your other routes which starts with some text.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'content/show_article_post/$1';
```

Also make sure your slug for each article is unique in your database. There is no other way to send hidden id from get request.